# Extracting day in Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am asked to extract information of employees who are hired on Saturday. I tried like the code given below. But even-though there are data's available, it shows me no data available

```
select first_name,last_name
  from employees
 where upper(to_char(hire_date,'day')) like 'SATURDAY'
```

But when I use the following code it works like champ. This code was given to me by my boss.

```
select first_name,last_name
  from employees
 WHERE TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'fmDay') = 'Saturday'
```

I want to know why my code doesn't work. Please explain. I am a newbie in oracle and working hard for finding the difference between one function and another.

Comment: this will help: http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/16087-difference-between-day-fmday-month-fmmonth.html#post50067

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TO_CHAR(hire_date,'day')` returns the day name, blank padded from the right to the length of the longest name of the week. As it happens to be `Wednesday` then each returned day's name that is shorter than 9 characters will be blank padded.

`like 'SATURDAY'` condition without wildcard characters is equivalent to `= 'SATURDAY'`.

So, `to_char(hire_date,'day')` returns `SATURDAY_`(where `_` is an extra space character) which is not equal to `SATURDAY`, thus your query returns no rows.

Use the `FM` format model modifier (`TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'fmDay')`) to get rid of those extra spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas  exactly the definition i am expecting.. Thanks a lot

Comment: some spelling mistakes after "So return.. equal 'SATURDAY' "..
And this too an understanding for the quesition: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10ce9/2/0

Answer (score 2):

Difference between day and fmday is, in fmday the embedded spaces can be removed by placing the 'fm' prefix.

Try this to get the result,

```
select first_name,last_name
  from employees
 where REPLACE(upper(to_char(hire_date,'day')),' ','') like 'SATURDAY'
```

Comment: Reference,
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Data-Type/TOCHARDatefmDayMonthfmDDYYYYEmbeddedspacescanberemovedbyplacingthefmprefix.htm

Comment: Wouldn't `trim` be simpler than `replace`?

Comment: Yes Alex, trim would be better and simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
  select to_char (date '2011-07-24', 'D') d from dual;
```

This query will return a number mapped to day so you can rewrite you query as

```
 select first_name,last_name
 from employees
 WHERE to_char (Hire_date '2011-07-24', 'D') d = 7
```

Comment: Yes Harshit i tried that too.. I just want to know why my query doesn't work... @Nicholas has explained it well

Answer (score 0):

Try to query using following statement to check the condition first:

```
select upper(to_char(hire_date,'day')) from employees
```